# Ramda: How to filter based on a value in a nested array

Tags: ramda.js

I'm trying to accomplish this in a functional manner (with Ramda). My JSON is structured like this

```
[
    {username: 'bob', age: 30, tags: ['work', 'boring']},
    {username: 'jim', age: 25, tags: ['home', 'fun']},
    {username: 'jane', age: 30, tags: ['vacation', 'fun']}
]
```

and I am trying to filter based on a value in the 'tags' property, but have not been successful.  I am able to filter on ints/strings (age and username), but I can't figure out how to do so with values in nested arrays (tags).  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are many ways you could do this.  But I think the cleanest one would be:

```
R.filter(R.where({tags: R.includes('fun')}))
```

You can see it in action in the **[Ramda REPL](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7Busername%3A%20%27bob%27%2C%20age%3A%2030%2C%20tags%3A%20%5B%27work%27%2C%20%27boring%27%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7Busername%3A%20%27jim%27%2C%20age%3A%2025%2C%20tags%3A%20%5B%27home%27%2C%20%27fun%27%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7Busername%3A%20%27jane%27%2C%20age%3A%2030%2C%20tags%3A%20%5B%27vacation%27%2C%20%27fun%27%5D%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0AR.filter%28R.where%28%7Btags%3A%20R.includes%28%27fun%27%29%7D%29%29%28data%29%3B%0A)**.

Other options, especially if the field is more deeply nested is to `compose` (or `pipe`) `prop` or `path` calls with `contains` or possibly to take advantage of lenses.

Still, I think the answer above is most readable.

Comment: that looks like a nice solution to me. And i like the way it reads: "filter where tags contains 'fun'" sounds very much like the problem description.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Since posting I came up with this `var byTag = R.curry(function(tag, items) {
      var containsTag = function(val) {
        return R.contains(tag, val.tags); 
      };
      return R.filter(containsTag, items);
    });` but it's definitely not as pretty as your solution.  For whatever reason using R.contains as the property value didn't even cross my mind.  Thanks again!

Comment: I don't know if other libraries with similar `where` functions also allow a predicate in this place.  We're pretty happy with this feature.

Comment: I've just started to venture into functional programming and I must say, your library is pretty sweet so far.

Comment: Thanks.  BTW, if you really wanted a points-free version of this, you could do something like this monstrosity: `var fn = R.useWith(R.filter, R.pipe(R.contains, R.createMapEntry('tags'), R.where), R.identity); fn('fun', data);`.  But _why_??  It's much less readable.

Comment: I altered the solution to access the username property, and it gave me an error `R.equals is not a function`. I don't understand why this won't work.  __[REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.13.0#?const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7Busername%3A%20%27bob%27%2C%20age%3A%2030%2C%20tags%3A%20%5B%27work%27%2C%20%27boring%27%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7Busername%3A%20%27jane%27%2C%20age%3A%2030%2C%20tags%3A%20%5B%27vacation%27%2C%20%27fun%27%5D%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0AR.filter%28R.where%28%7Busername%3A%20R.equals%28%27jane%27%29%7D%29%29%28data%29%3B%0A)__

Comment: @garajo: Your REPL URL points to v0.13 of Ramda.  `equals` wasn't added until v0.15.

Answer (score 3):

```
const arr = [
 {username: 'bob', age: 30, tags: ['work', 'boring']},
 {username: 'jim', age: 25, tags: ['home', 'fun']},
 {username: 'jane', age: 30, tags: ['vacation', 'fun']}
];

res = R.filter(R.where({tags: R.contains('home')}), arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [
             {username: 'bob', age: 30, tags: ['work', 'boring']},
             {username: 'jim', age: 25, tags: ['home', 'fun']},
             {username: 'jane', age: 30, tags: ['vacation', 'fun']}
           ];
const filtTags = R.compose(R.filter, R.where({tags: R.includes('fun')})
const result = filtTags(arr)
```