# Delete object by id from array Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I want to delete object from array by id using Ramda. For example:

```
const arr = [
  {id: '1', name: 'Armin'},
  {id: '2', name: 'Eren'}, <- delete this object
  {id: '3', name: 'Mikasa'}
];
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Its a fairly simple operation.

Comment: @Rajesh, sure, I've tried to use R.filter(), R.reject(), but I still new in Ramda

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29254470/ramda-how-to-filter-based-on-a-value-in-a-nested-array

Comment: Try `R.filter(({ id }) => id !== '2', arr)`. For more info, refer: https://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#filter. Also a pointer, when you ask a question, please share your attempt in question. That makes a requirement, problem and we could help accordingly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can user `filter` function, with a composed functions `propEq & not`

```
const result = filter(
  compose(
   not,
   propEq('id', 2)
  ),
  array,
)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I don't see how `filter + complement(propEq)` would be a better solution than using `reject(propEq)`...

Comment: @Hitmands there are a lot of ways in a ramda to handle such case, regarding `reject` it is the exactly same as  `filter + complement(propEq)` check the implementation on [github](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/source/reject.js)

Comment: Of course it is, the issue is about readability... at high level, reject reads better than negating filter... and that is why reject exists.

Answer (score 7):

You can use both `filter` or `reject`:

```
R.reject(o => o.id === '2', arr);

R.filter(o => o.id !== '2', arr);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `reject`.

> The reject() is a complement to the filter(). It excludes elements of
>   a filterable for which the predicate returns true.

```
let res = R.reject(R.propEq('id', '2'))(arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
// you could create a generic rejectWhere function
const rejectWhere = (arg, data) => R.reject(R.whereEq(arg), data);


const arr = [
  {id: '1', name: 'Armin'},
  {id: '2', name: 'Eren'}, // <- delete this object
  {id: '3', name: 'Mikasa'}
];


console.log(
  'result', 
  rejectWhere({ id: '2' }, arr),
);

// but also
// rejectWhere({ name: 'Eren' }, arr),
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-xB25ljGZ7K2VXnq087unEnoVhvTosWWtqXB4tAtZmHU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```