# Ramda reject - is there a more elegant way to write this?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

```
const people = [
  {
    name: 'bill',
    age: 52
  },
  {
    name: 'james',
    age: 27
  },
  {
    name: 'james',
    age: 17
  }
]

const newPeople = R.reject(person => {
  return R.includes('jam', person.name)
})(people)
```

Is there a more elegant *Ramda* way to write this? I am looking to return an array that removes all people objects that have the string `jam` in their name.

Perhaps something like `R.reject(R.where(...))` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you were on the right track with `where`.

This reads quite well to me:

```js
const jamless = reject (where ({name: includes ('jam')}))

const people = [{name: 'bill', age: 52}, {name: 'james', age: 27}, {name: 'james', age: 17}]

console .log (
  jamless (people)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {reject, where, includes} = R                 </script>
```

Reading the keywords aloud, we can hear "reject where name includes 'jam'", not a bad English description of the problem.

If you want to parameterize this, it could just be

```js
const disallow = (str) => reject (where ({name: includes(str)}) )
const jamless = disallow ('jam')
```

(Although I'm quite sure we could make a point-free version of `disallow`, I see no reason to try, as this is already quite readable.)

See also the related answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/29256202

Comment: maybe show that `name` can easily be parameterized too?

Comment: @user633183: Sure, `const disallow = (prop) => (val) => reject (where ({[prop]: includes(val)}) )`, but somewhere you need to get back to the generic usage of `where` too; this is starting to push the boundaries for me.

Comment: Yep. I ended up with `R.reject(R.where({ name: R.includes('jam') }));` which is exactly what you proposed here. Always nice to get a response from Ramda developer! :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would break this down into smaller functions:

**withJam**

Returns `true` if a string contains the string `jam` (case insensitive)

```
const withJam = R.test(/jam/i);
withJam('Bill') //=> false
withJam('James') //=> true
```

**nameWithJam**

Returns `true` if a property contains the string `jam` (case insensitive)

```
const nameWithJam = R.propSatisfies(withJam, 'name');
nameWithJam({name: 'Bill'}) //=> false
nameWithJam({name: 'James'}) //=> true
```

Then you can write:

```
R.reject(nameWithJam)(people)
```

---

I think that your initial solution is good enough already. I just made it pointfree, i.e. without mentioning the parameters explicitly.

Example:

Let's say that you need a function that adds `5` to any number:

```
const add5 = n => n + 5;
add5(37) //=> 42
```

You could get rid of `n` if you could work with a curried version of `add`. Let's define `add` first:

```
const add = m => n => m + n;
```

Then let's create `add5`:

```
const add5 = add(5);
add5(37) //=> 42
```

You can replace this:

```
[1,2,3].map(n => n + 5) //=> [6,7,8]
```

With:

```
[1,2,3].map(add(5)) //=> [6,7,8]
```

⚠️ Pointfree style is certainly interesting and worth exploring. But it can also unnecessarily complicate things :) See [When is it appropriate to choose point-free style vs a data-centric style in functional programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53670665/1244884)

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with this approach, and it's a well-written answer (upvoted!)  But I think my answer shows a cleaner implementation.

Comment: Agreed. I rarely think of using where. Nice!

Comment: `where` was featured in the [very first article](http://buzzdecafe.github.io/code/2014/05/16/introducing-ramda) written about Ramda, more than five years ago.  And I still sometimes forget about it.