# Ramda filter data with gte condition

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, filtering, ramda.js

I have JSON with data

```
 {
   "date": "2019-12-17",
   "installs": 1,
 },
 {
   "date": "2019-12-02",
   "installs": 5
 },
 {
   "date": "2019-12-02",
   "installs": 4
 }
 ....
```

and i need to filter this by gte condition on one field (installs, for example)

i tried with this code:

```
    let f = R.filter(R.propIs(true, R.gte(R.prop('installs'), 2)), data);
    console.log(f)
```

but got error

```
TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
```

Comment: [Ramda: How to filter based on a value in a nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29256202) You can use `where` as shown in this answer

Comment: eg: `R.filter(R.where({'installs': gte(R.__, 3)}), data);`

Comment: @NickParsons can i use multiple conditions, like gte 3 lt 10?

Comment: Perhaps try using `and`: `filter(where({'installs': and(gte(__, 3), lt(__, 10))}), data);`

Comment: Yep, it's working, thanks )

Comment: @NickParsons maybe you know, how i can pass filter params from object (without R.)?

Comment: Hm, could you clarify what you're trying to do? I'm not super sure I understand what you're after

Comment: For example, i have form where i set from and to amount of installs, and send object to function {installs: gte: 5 lt: 15}. How to use it as filter conditions? But it also can be not "installs", i can pass "date" as filtration key @NickParsons

Comment: It's possible to do, but I can't think of a clean functional programming way of doing it. Perhaps ask another question or ask Scott below who's good with fp and Rambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your attempt shows some confusion about how to use Ramda's ideas on functional composition.  Probably the working version closest to yours would look like this:

```js
filter(pipe (prop ('installs'), gte (__, 2), equals (true)), data)
```

I will pull out and name the function passed to `filter` for our discussion.  If you have no other use for it, of course it can be inlined again later.

```js
const enoughInstalls = pipe (prop ('installs'), gte (__, 2), equals (true))
filter (enoughInstalls) (data)
```

Note that when we want to create a function that passes data from one function to another, we don't nest them with something like `gte(prop('installs'), 2)`.  Because `prop('installs')` is a *function*, this would entail passing a *function* as the first argument to `gte`.  Of course you need to pass a number instead.  When we want to pass the *results* of one function call to another, we use functional composition, usually using Ramda's [`compose`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose) or its [`pipe`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe).  We'll do the latter here, but `compose` is quite similar, simply with the arguments reversed.

So instead of `gte(prop('installs'), 2)` we use `pipe(prop('installs'), gte(__, 2))`.  This returns a function which passes its argument(s) to `prop('installs')` and passes the result of that call to `gte(__, 2)`.  Above there is one more call in the pipeline, `equals(true)`.  That's trying to match your `propIs` idea.  But it turns out to be entirely unnecessary.  `gte` will return a boolean.  So adding `equals(true)` to that simply returns the same boolean.  So this can be simplified to:

```js
const enoughInstalls = pipe (prop ('installs'), gte (__, 2))
```

This now says to grab the property `installs` from our input object and pass it to the predicate function `gte(__, 2)`.  But there is a built-in function for that, [`propSatisfies`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#propSatisfies).  We could rewrite this to:

```js
const enoughInstalls = propSatisfies (gte (__, 2), 'installs')
```

This is a perfectly reasonable solution.  But I actually prefer the version Nick Parsons suggested in the comments.  For this one, I really prefer to inline in the `filter` call:

```js
const myFilter = filter (where ({installs: gte(__, 2)})
```

Reading that aloud as "filter where installs is greater than or equal to 2" makes this almost as readable as can be imagined.